# IronPython import modules

Tags: ironpython

I have just started using IronPython and I am confused around where the modules are imported from.

I am wanting to do some XML parsing and have tried to import xml.sax however it says that these modules are not present.  I have Python 2.4 and 2.6 installed on my machine and they both have the xml.sax folders/modules there?

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: IronPython includes many standard library modules, including the PYTHONIC xml.etree.ElementTree - friendlier than any .NET option.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned [here](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=List%20of%20Standard%20Library%20components%20not%20included%20in%20the%20MSI) xml.sax is not a part of the standard MSI of IronPython

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll have a look at importing System.Xml from the clr instead.